# Instantiating AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient in Unity 2020.3.26f, WebGL build, gives the error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream"

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-dynamodb, webgl

I've been working on a Unity WebGL project, with Unity version 2020.3.26f, which aims to use AWS DynamoDB as its database. The project includes all the AWS SDK dll's, downloaded and compiled from the following link: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=id%3AAWSSDK%20owner%3Aawsdotnet

The project builds without issues, but when run, the following line of code:
`cognitoProvider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), RegionAWS);`

Generates the following error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zJAi.png)
`

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean leaveOpen) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

Has someone faced this issue before? Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

I have tried:

- Updating the dlls
- Change the unity version to 2019.x.x and to 2021.x.x
- Building a clean project with only the specified line.